# How do I add gap between rows in table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "wall" as in linkedin and I'm doing that by creating a long table. I've changed background color and table color to give contrast. My issue is that I can't separate my table rows so that the background color shows between them.

All of the examples I find use

```
<table style="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing:0 1rem;">
```

How do I color in the spacing to match the background?

Or are there better ways of solving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill color in border spacing between cells in HTML using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828017/how-to-fill-color-in-border-spacing-between-cells-in-html-using-css)

Comment: Try applying color not to the `table` but to `td`s, and add row gap by `tr {margin-bottom: 10px}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it exactly the way you want. Your options are:

- add padding to every cell in the desired row: `tr.this-one td { padding-bottom: 1em;}`. This will use cells' background color.
- add thick border to every cell in the desired row: `tr.this-one td { border-bottom: 1em solid red;}`. This will use border color you set, which you can make to match the background color you have.
- add a row in the markup: `<tr><td colspan="10"></td></tr>` and style it the way you'd like. You can also have `<thead>`/`<tfoot>`/[multiple `<tbody>` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element) inside a table as a way to semantically group rows (but they're not styleable by themselves).

Answer (score 0):

#### *Hi*

Maybe this will help. I put table into a div container and set it background. Then if you need to have another color between rows just change `background-color` property of table, because now is `transparent` should be same as container background.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0rem 1rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

tr {
    background-color: tomato;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>mallard</td>
      <td>colorful</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dog</td>
      <td>piebald</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fox</td>
      <td>foxy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### *Cheers*